# fire one of multiple events jquery - prevent redandency triggres

Tags: event-handling, jquery

I want to attach an event handler function for **one of the three events** to the selected elements.

e.g if `event1` and `event2` fired, I want to execute the code just once, and prevent function trigger redundancy.

```
$('#myelement').on('event1 event2 event3', function(){
    /* do things here just once */
});
```

Is there an easy way to do this, without using any boolean.

**EDIT :**
Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/BLLxF/  if you paste e.g. **"test"** it display **"Fired Fried"**, I just want to display **"Fired"** (It's just an example)

Comment: [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method.

Comment: Already tried it, `The handler is executed at most once per element` it's not what I want.

Comment: @Ouadie what do you want then?

Comment: Presumably he wants the element to respond to one of the three events (every time they might happen), presumably the first, without the other two firing as well at that point.